# Webhook for Github and Jenkins not working

Tags: jenkins, github, amazon-ec2, build, ngrok

My goal is to trigger Jenkins build upon any commit in GitHub. I have configured the GitHub webhook with below

http://d36dxxxc.ngrok.io/payload. However when I when I commit in the Github. I see that there is not build is triggered in the Jenkins.

And back in the Webhook response I always see the below message.

```
Tunnel d36dxxxc.ngrok.io not found
```

In the jenkin->Configure "Build Trigger" I have selected "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" and "Poll SCM" options

My Request in Webhook looks like:

```
Request URL: http://d36d854c.ngrok.io/payload
Request method: POST
content-type: application/json
Expect: 
User-Agent: GitHub-Hookshot/89e91ff
X-GitHub-Delivery: 6893acfa-8844-11e8-9e02-9168bb29d973
X-GitHub-Event: push
```

However in the Response I always see like this:

```
Tunnel d36dxxxc.ngrok.io not found
```

And nothing happens on the Jenkins build.

Comment: (a) If you were trying to hide your actual ngrok URL you've failed. It's fully listed in your "Request in Webhook" section. (b) It certainly looks like there is no tunnel at that address (exactly what the error message is telling you). Are you sure you've set one up, and that it's running?

Comment: Hi jonrsharpe, Thanks for your response. I tried everything again with port 4567 now.

Comment: I tried everything carefully this time by setting my ngrok at port 4567: And I have enabled the port 4567 from the security group->Inbound 
This time I am getting some error 502 however it failed with a useful message in the Response
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Failed to complete tunnel connection
    The connection to  http://561768dd.ngrok.io
    was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client,
    but the client failed to establish a connection to
    the local address  localhost:4567 Make sure that a web service is running on localhost

Comment: First of all, johnrsharpe edited your question but didn't comment. I'm an entirely different person. Now that that's out of the way, you've got a clear error message. It looks like you're having trouble working with ngrok. Forget about GitHub and Jenkins for now; can you get the ngrok tunnel running? _Are_ you running a web service on your local machine?

Comment: Hello Chris, My sincere apologies. I didn't notice your name in the first response. Thanks a lot. Yes the tunnel is running ++++++++++++++++++
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                                                 
Forwarding   http://561768dd.ngrok.io -> localhost:4567
Forwarding    https://561768dd.ngrok.io -> localhost:4567

Comment: sudo ./ngrok http 4567

ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                                                 

Session Status                online
Session Expires               7 hours, 58 minutes
Version                       2.2.8
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://561768dd.ngrok.io -> localhost:4567
Forwarding                    https://561768dd.ngrok.io -> localhost:4567

Comment: However I am not sure about the Webservice

Comment: Could you please help me running the webservice. I thought the .ngrok itself acts as a webservice. Also I had another question, if & when we succeed the build is triggering in Jenkins, into which directory it would actually build the files ? Do I need to create any folder on my  server. Thanks in advance, I appreciate your help.

Comment: ngrok acts as a _tunnel_, exposing a web service that you're running inside your local network to the Internet at large. What are you trying to open up to the world? Presumably something that Jenkins is supposed to be doing? You've told ngrok that it's running on your local machine on port 4567. (And please don't ask new questions in comments. Focus on this one for now.)

Comment: Actually , I got your point Chris. My webservice is tomcat itself which is running at port 8080. So now I changed the port number to 8080 in my ngrok command. Still I receive a "302 Found" message at the server where ngrok tunnel is running kindly see the below ngrok output.******************

Comment: ec2-user 20363 20147  0 08:54 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ngrok
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-247 software]$ ./ngrok http 8080
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                                                    (Ctrl+C to quit)
Session Status                online
Session Expires               6 hours, 48 minutes
Version                       2.2.8
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://a6a46126.ngrok.io -> localhost:8080

Comment: Forwarding                    https://a6a46126.ngrok.io -> localhost:8080

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              4       0       0.00    0.00    20.01   20.02

HTTP Requests
-------------

POST /jenkins                  302 Found
POST /payload                  302 Found
POST /payload                  302 Found

Comment: And I see the below message at my webhook response side:                            Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 967
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 17 Jul 2018 09:17:43 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

Comment: Wait, are you doing all of this on an EC2 instance? (I see "ec2-user".) If so you can probably just open up access to Jenkins and forget about ngrok altogether. In any case, [302 Found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) is an HTTP redirect. It looks like appending `/payload` to your GitHub webhook URL might help.

Comment: Hi, Chris, yes I am using EC2 instance on which I configured jenkins build. I specified the repository url: in the "Source Code Management" section. and in the "Build Triggers" section I selected "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" and "Poll SCM" options. Still that was not kicking of the build when I committ any new changes. Thats why I went on checking the ngrok route. Could you please suggest what is stopping the build to happen please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Bye the way, the only time my webhook seems to be working is if I dont add any payload in the end of webhook url e.g http://a6a46126.ngrok.io/. Then I see a Response code 200 OK and it is sending the tomcat home page back to the webhook response tab.

Comment: If you're using EC2 I don't think you need ngrok at all. The only reason for using ngrok is to create a tunnel from the public internet to your local network but with EC2 you can simply make the port available. I'd recommend getting rid of ngrok entirely to simplify the problem.